# input not working while running in debug mode - eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Standard input works fine when I run my program, but doesn't work when in debugging mode, although output works fine as well.
I'm running Eclipse Photon (4.8) with CDT and for my toolchain I use `gcc` provided by Cygwin and I use `gdb` as my debugger.
[Output when I run the program without debugging](http://prntscr.com/kakx5i)
[Output when I run the program with debugging, mind the variable watches and the console](http://prntscr.com/kakzk0)

The Cygwin toolchain is detected automatically because it is present in the PATH environment variable, I also reset the workspace, but that didn't help.

UPDATE: If I put multiple `cin` lines one after another, the first `cin` will return a number different from that in the input and every consecutive `cin` will return a zero as a value.

UPDATE2: I found a workaround. If you use an external console (`cmd`) instead of the one in Eclipse, then it works. [Image](http://prntscr.com/kalgg5)

Comment: a stupid workaround is to manually edit the values in the "variable watch" window

Comment: yet another workaround would be to use a file instead of stdin, but that is not what i need

Comment: [Possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313245/program-input-cin-or-getline-is-read-in-correct-when-running-but-not-when-debu/43315953).

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604947/using-fgetschar-c-int-i-file-f-with-printf-for-c-in-eclipse-cdt-the-o/43160445), perhaps you're running into that issue.

Comment: @HighCommander4 the first link isn't helpful, since I have gdb 7.12.1 and CDT 9.5.1

Comment: the weirdest part is that it used to work, but now it obviously doesn't

Comment: @HighCommander4 the second link also isn't helpful, since I use `cout` which flushes by default

Comment: i don't know if i should try reinstalling eclipse and instead of cygwin use mingw

Comment: speaking of, should i use mingw or mingw-w64?

Comment: I thought `cout` only flushed if you use `std::endl`, not `"\n"`.

Comment: As for your other questions, no idea, sorry; I stay far away from Windows these days.

Comment: @HighCommander4 yeah, the `endl` flushes the buffer

Comment: And the code in your screenshot does not use `endl`.